# How to get all emails from a page individually

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-re

I am trying to get all emails from a specific page and separate them into an individual variable or even better a dictionary. This is some code.

```
import requests
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = "http://www.example.net"
info = requests.get(page)
if info.status_code == 200:
    print("Page accessed")
else:
    print("Error accessing page")
code = info.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(code, 'lxml')
allEmails = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"^mailto:"))
print(allEmails)
sep = ","
allEmailsStr = str(allEmails)
print(type(allEmails))
print(type(allEmailsStr))
j = allEmailsStr.split(sep, 1)[0]
print(j)
```

Excuse the poor variable names because I put this together so it would be fine by itself. The output from the example website would be for example something like

```
[<a href="mailto:k@domain.xyz">k</a>, <a href="mailto:russia@siberia.net">kolyma</a>, <a href="mailto:house@chinatown.com">location</a>, <a href="mailto:sophia@bulgaria.cf">balkans</a>]
```

So if I ran the problem it would return only

```
[<a href ="mailto:k@domain.xyz">k</a>
```

But if I wanted it to return every email on there individually how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your expected output, you can use the `unwrap` function of `BeautifulSoup`

```py
allEmails = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"^mailto:"))
for Email in allEmails:
   print(Email.unwrap()) #This will print the whole element along with tag
                         # <a href="mailto:k@domain.xyz">k</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get just the email str you can try:

```
emails = []

for email_link in allEmails:
    emails.append(email_link.get("href").replace('mailto:', ''))

print(emails)
```